# Lighttpd : proxy on another local website

Tags: unix, https, proxy, reverse-proxy, lighttpd

I'm currently stuck on a proxy problem : I use lighttpd to serve html pages on port 443, and now I want to access another local website (only accessible with localhost) and with https, while he can't handle it.

My solution's to use lighttpd as proxy to redirect all requests of the interface 192.168.x.x: in the local interface (127.0.0.1:).

As example, if my local server's on port 8080, all the 192.168.x.x:8080 are redirect on 127.0.0.1:8080, but the url in my browser still 192.168.x.x:8080. With this configuration, i can let lighttpd setup https.

But now I'm stuck on the redirection, i use [mod_proxy](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy) but nothing work and the page can't be found :

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "192.168.x.x:8080" {
  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/server.pem"
  proxy.server  = ( "" => (
    "api:8080" => # name
      ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", # Set the IP address of servername
        "port" => 8080
      )
    )
  )
}
```

what did a do wrong ?
Thanks in advance !

PS : I use the version 1.4.53 of lighttpd

**EDIT**
To be more precise, I just want a basic proxy usage from ligttpd :

[image]

I add ssl engine and ssl pemfile for my 8080 port listener

Comment: Your question is not very clear on who is connecting from where, and whether the connection is http or https.  The above config snippet looks fine for cleartext requests from clients.  If you expect lighttpd to use TLS with clients, then you have to configure TLS in lighttpd, e.g. `ssl.engine = "enable"` in `$SERVER["socket"]`.

Comment: You cant use port 8080 for both.  Configure your lighthttpd to answer on port 443.  Configure your other site to listin on port 8080.  All connections to host:443 will proxy to host:8080.  The configuration seems to me like you are trying to get host:8080 of lighthttpd proxy host:8080, the other site.

Comment: I edit my question @gstrauss, hope that help you to understand

Comment: Not useful: "But now I'm stuck on the redirection, i use mod_proxy but nothing work".  Add to lighttpd.conf `proxy.debug = 3`, restart lighttpd, make a request, and look in the lighttpd error log.

Comment: Check if your server on localhost 127.0.0.1:8080 is receiving the request, and how the request is being handled.